# Figure out a image attached to a imageview when called through a event handler JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have an event handler attached to 9 different images labeled a.png through to i.png, I'm trying to figure out a way of detecting which image (a-i) the user has clicked on and execute logic for different images.

An example with a single image is below.

```
Image img = new Image("a.png");
ImageView pieceIV = new ImageView();
pieceIV.setImage(img);

pieceIV.setOnMouseClicked(gameLogic.MouseClickEvent);

public static EventHandler<MouseEvent> MouseClickEvent = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        // Need to figure out the images name or parse the name to the event handler somehow.

    }
};
```

Any ideas?

Sincerely Ben.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Done. :) If I haven't made it clearer please let me know. :)

Comment: where do you see the similarity of your snippets with the example suggested on the help page ;)

Comment: Would this be the "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" help page?

Answer (score 0):

There are many simple ways to identify which `ImageView` was clicked. Here is one using `setId()` and `getId()` :

```
public class FxTest extends Application {

    private String[] urls = {
                "https://findicons.com/files/icons/345/summer/128/cake.png",
                "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/atyourservice/service-categories/128/Sweets-icon.png",
                "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS_FkBgG3_ux0kCbfG8mcRHvdk1dYbZYsm2SFMS01YvA6B_zfH_kg",
              };

    private static int uid = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TilePane root = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL,5,5);
        root.setPrefColumns(3);
        root.getChildren().addAll(getImageView(), getImageView(), getImageView());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ImageView getImageView() {

        Image image = new Image(urls[uid%3]);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setId(String.valueOf(uid++)); 

        imageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("image id "+ imageView.getId() + " clicked");
            }
        });
        return imageView;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(Relating to the comments about mcve: the above code, after adding the needed imports, can serve as an example for mcve)

Comment: Would this still work if the event handler was external from the getImageView Method? (About to test this)

Comment: I gave this a go, one issue is having an external event handler means that the imageView variable isn't accessible. I have 10 image views all generated through a for loop which makes accessing them a bit difficult.

So in my event handler code I have no way of calling imageView, I can use the event.getSource() to retrieve the image view however then using getId() doesn't appear to be valid. i.e.
event.getSource().getId()